# How do I open OLEDB Prompt for 32-bit from x64

Tags: c#, x86, 64-bit, oledb, adodb

Good day everyone,

I am writing a C# application that will allow users to dynamically set the database they want to connect to (I'll work a bit with the database data and such, but that's not important). The important part is that I'm allowing my users to connect to data-stores from OLEDB using the code below.

```
ADODB.Connection connection;
MSDASC.DataLinks instance = new MSDASC.DataLinksClass();
if( (connection = instance.PromptNew() as ADODB.Connection) == null ) return;
```

This will open the very same Dialog that windows opens for *.udl files, and that's exactly what I want.
     However, I hit a interesting problem to which your brightness could come in handy: some customer WILL have to browse for x86 drivers, and the vast majority will certainly use x64.

I know you can open x86 UDL files with the following command-line:
**"C:\Windows\syswow64\rundll32.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\Ole DB\oledb32.dll",OpenDSLFile "C:\myConnectionFile.udl"**

When the default (64 bit) command is:

**"C:\Program Files\Common Files\System\Ole DB\oledb32.dll",OpenDSLFile  "C:\myConnectionFile.udl"**

In other words: windows' allowing users to create entries in both fashion. I would like to do the same in my app, using the API.
      I have considered the option of creating a temp UDL file and opening from the command-line above, which made my conversation with my technical lead rather unpleasant, so that's not an option.

All suggestions are welcome. I will not dismiss unsafe coding nor the thought of building wrapper in C++ if we get to that (although my C++ is inconveniently rusty nowadays).

Thank you all in advance and happy coding...

Answer (score 0):

Good day fellow developers,

After a tedious and lengthy research process I have around the answer I was looking for.
 In order to use OLEDB providers for both 32 and 64 bit platform from one single C# 64bit app I'll need to create an Out-of-Process Wrapper to the 32bit call, and make the call over IPC (Internal Process Calls). Because the amount of functionalities I'm exposing is moderate, the hindrance was just re-creating some method calls on the wrapper.

[This blog](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2014/01/07/hosting-a-net-dll-as-an-out-of-process-com-server/) helped me put the parts together, and now I'm able to determine what type of OLEDB connection I'll allow my user create, and I'm also able to perform all operations I need regardless of the Provider Architecture.

I hope this will benefit other people who might be having the issue.

If time (and NDA) allows, I'll get the code here for people to copy and try it later.

These links were also very useful on my research

http://blog.mattmags.com/2007/06/30/accessing-32-bit-dlls-from-64-bit-code/

Registering the DLL Server for Surrogate Activation 
https: // msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686606(v=vs.85).aspx)

Writing Serviced Component
https: // msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3x7357ez(VS.80).aspx)

How to: Create Serviced Component
https: // msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty17dz7h(VS.80).aspx)

Create Out-Of-Process COM in C#/.Net?http: // stackoverflow.com/questions/446417/create-out-of-process-com-in-c-net

Thanks everyone

D